# ld: cannot find -lkeyutils in gcc

Tags: c, gcc

I am a begginer all arroung gcc compiling. i have some program in c which there i try to compile in order to run it in Android devices.

currently i succeded to compile it under 64 bit but it is not running in the android device so i would like to try it in 32 bit mode.

when i compile it i execute it succesfully:

```
gcc  cve_2016_0728.c -o cve_2016_0728 -lkeyutils -Wall -Woverflow
```

when i try to execute it in 32 bit mode with the following command i get:

```
gcc -m32 cve_2016_0728.c -o cve_2016_0728 -lkeyutils -Wall -Woverflow
```

error:

```
 cve_2016_0728.c: In function ‘main’:
    cve_2016_0728.c:55:11: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
  } msg = {0x4141414141414141, {0}};
           ^
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lkeyutils
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You have 2 problems, one is that you have an overflow and the second is that your library can't be found.

So, first off, you have to fix the conversion and 2nd, you have to find a 32bit version of keyutils library on your system.  

Since you don't post a [mcve], we can't help with the first and the 2nd is up to you.

Comment: do you know where i can find 32bit vewrsion?because in google is not available

Comment: You'll have to at least tell us what you're trying to do and what functions call the keyutils library - right now we know nothing about what you're doing.

Comment: If you need the 32bit version, perhaps you can [download](http://people.redhat.com/~dhowells/keyutils/) it and compile it yourself (you may need to change the `Makefile` so that 32bit code is generated)